# Proof of the residue formula Res$(f(z);z_0) = -\frac{q''(z_0)}{(q'(z_0))^3}$ for a pole of order two

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus

Suppose $f(z) = \frac{1}{(q(z))^2}$ where $q(z_0) = 0$ and $q'(z_0) \neq 0$

Show that Res$(f(z);z_0) = -\frac{q''(z_0)}{(q'(z_0))^3}$

I been messing around with $f$ for quite a while and honestly I have no idea how to even start.

Any help or insights (or point me in the right direction) is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I have modified your title in order that your question is better refrenced. Do you agree.

Comment: See as well (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552492)

Comment: I see, thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $z_0=0$. We have
\begin{align}
q(z)&=q'(0)\,z+\frac{q''(0)}{2}\,z^2+O(z^3)\\
(q(z))^2&=(q'(0)^2)\,z^2+q'(0)\,q''(0)\,z^3+O(z^4)\\
\frac{1}{q(z)^2}&=\frac{1}{(q'(0)^2)\,z^2}\Biggl(\frac{1}{1+\dfrac{q''(0)}{q'(0)}\,z+O(z^2)}\Biggr)\\
&=\frac{1}{(q'(0)^2)\,z^2}\Bigl(1-\frac{q''(0)}{q'(0)}\,z+O(z^2)\Bigr).
\end{align}

Comment: First question, why may we assume WLOG ?

Comment: @some1: Because we can translate any given problem to an equivalent problem. (and, the equivalent problem even has the *same* answer, rather than just giving a result that we have to transform back to be the answer to the original problem)

Comment: Consider $f(z+z_0)$. $0\leftrightarrow z_0$ and $z\leftrightarrow z-z_0$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Last question though, how did you get from 2nd last line to the last line ? negative binomial ?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1+z}=1-z+O(z^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f$ has a pole of order 2 at $z_0$ (why?), so the Laurent series of $f$ will be
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-2}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)^n,$$
while
$$
q(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n(z - z_0)^n,\qquad\text{with } b_n = \cdots
$$
Use now that
$$f(z)q(z)^2 = 1.$$